# Syntax for using postgresql array overlay operator in queryDSL

Tags: postgresql, jpa, querydsl

I am trying to construct a query that uses postgresql's array overlay operator in queryDSL + JPA, using BooleanBuilder's and boolean template's, however I cannot get JPA to accept my query. The way I have it written currently is

```java
    public BooleanBuilder addUUIDListIntersectionCondition(BooleanBuilder clause,
        CollectionPath<UUID, ComparablePath<UUID>> arg0, List<UUID> arg1) {
        clause.and(Expressions.booleanTemplate("{0} && ARRAY[{1}::UUID]", arg0,
            String.join(",", arg1.stream().map(a -> a.toString()).collect(Collectors.toList()))));
    }
```

but this results in the following exception:

```
An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: 
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [select ec
from vw_ec ec
where ec.orgUserIds && ARRAY[?1::UUID]]. 
[76, 193] The expression is not a valid conditional expression.; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: 
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [select ec
from vw_ec ec
where ec.orgUserIds && ARRAY[?1::UUID]]. 
[76, 193] The expression is not a valid conditional expression.
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:374)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.DefaultJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(DefaultJpaDialect.java:128)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:528)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
```

Running a similar query directly in postgresql works as intended:

```sql
select *
    from ec ec
    where (ec.orgUserIds && array['c61d452e-0361-11eb-8ecd-9e48108033fa', 'c623fc2d-0361-11eb-8ecd-9e48108033fa'::UUID])
```

Any ideas on where I'm going wrong?

Comment: I've attempted wrapping the overlay oeprator in a database function and calling that instead, but now I get

Internal Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.structures.ArrayMapping cannot be cast to class org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.CollectionMapping 

when I try to call that function.

Comment: Let me know if you already figured out how working booleanTemplate should be composed with exactly the same query ec.orgUserIds && array['c61d452e-0361-11eb-8ecd-9e48108033fa', 'c623fc2d-0361-11eb-8ecd-9e48108033fa']::uuid[]. I faced with the same problem.

Comment: I have managed to make workable only such a query c.orgUserIds && array['c61d452e-0361-11eb-8ecd-9e48108033fa']::uuid[]  where arg1 has only one element using booleanTemplate:
"Expressions.booleanTemplate("{0} && ARRAY[{1}]::uuid[]", ec.orgUserIds, StringUtils.collectionToDelimitedString(arg1, ",", "'", "'"))"

But this syntax doesn't work for me if arg1 has more than 1 element - throws PostgresqlBadGrammarException: incorrect UUID length. QueryDSL template looks like interpretate the whole input parameter for ARRAY as a string. Using string_to_array instead of ARRAY doesn't help me as well

Answer (score 0):

Don't think I have clean solution but it works for the following query:

```
select *
from ...
where '{e48f54d5-9845-4987-a53d-e0ecfe3dbb43,e48f54d5-9845-4987-a53d-e0ecfe3dbb45}'::uuid[] && '{e48f54d5-9845-4987-a53d-e0ecfe3dbb40,e48f54d5-9845-4987-a53d-e0ecfe3dbb45}'::uuid[];
```

I use the following syntax in `booleanTemplate`:

```
select(...)
.from(...)
.where(new BooleanBuilder().and(Expressions.booleanTemplate("{0} && {1}::uuid[]", arg0, String.format("{%s}", arg1.stream().map(UUID::toString).collect(joining(",")))))
```

Comment: Oh interesting, so you were able to get it to work by using the booleanTemplate in the select statement rather than inside the where? That's better than not being able to use it all but would be nice to be able to filter by the function as well.

Comment: I've been trying your suggestion but I always get an error in JPA before the query actually executes.

[1258, 1504] The expression is not a valid conditional expression.
[1504, 1814] The query contains a malformed ending.]
2020-10-16 22:09:57.230 DEBUG 10 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor : Closing JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor

Comment: I corrected answer that it'll be clear a bit. BooleanTemplate is used in where clause. Try this example.